# CC541 microcontroller

Tags: microcontroller, soc

I am trying to use the SoC CC2541 which is from Texas Instruments and is mounted with an 8051 mcu. I know that the firmware can be flashed through an Arduino board but as I want to avoid using an Arduino for flashing and uploading code to this mcu, I think that it is a waste of time and resources.

Is there any way to work with this mcu without using an Arduino? Maybe implementing an interface with a homemade pcb with an USB or something like that?

Here there are the datasheet of the [CC2541](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/cc2541.pdf)

Comment: well, you'll need *something* that talks to the debugging interface to program the thing. I don't know whether anything easier than using an arduino exists. Anyway, product recommendations are explicitly off-topic here. So, I'd recommend phrasing your question more precisely, addressing what you've found out about the programming interface so far.

Comment: on dev boards and even real systems it's not at all unusual to use one micro to program another. I have an STM32 board here for a chip with no USB interface, they put another micro from the same family on the board that does do USB and that is used for both JTAG interface and USB virtual port. In the end pretty much any programmer you use will be driven by a microcontroller of some sort. Why not just do what is easiest and gets you running?

Comment: You are right, if that's the standard, I guess that it must be the easier way. In this regard, how would you recommend me to work with the CC2541, using the arduino as an intermediary?